# AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'TrackerMOSSE_create'

Tags: python, opencv, moose, tracker

As the Dan's suggestion, i tried to edit this post
Error occurred at setting up MOOSE tracker, I also don't know why this error happened because i installed the Opencv-contrib-python==4.5.1.48.However,aftering installing it,the error is still there. The only tracker is MIL,but i realized that the usage purpose of two trackers is different. I also tried to code *tracker = cv2.legacy.TrackerMOSSE_create()* like Spyke's suggestion but nothing changes.
This is my code:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

tracker = cv2.TrackerMOSSE_create()
success, img = cap.read()

# select a bounding box ( ROI )
bbox = cv2.selectROI("Tracking", img, False)
tracker.init(img, bbox)


def drawBox(img, bbox):
    x, y, w, h = int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1]), int(bbox[2]), int(bbox[3])
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 255), 3, 1)
    cv2.putText(img, "Tracking", (75, 75), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 255, 0), 2)


while True:
    timer = cv2.getTickCount()
    success, img = cap.read()

    success, bbox = tracker.update(img)

    if success:
        drawBox(img, bbox)
    else:
        cv2.putText(img, "Loss", (75, 75), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)

    fps = cv2.getTickFrequency() / (cv2.getTickCount() - timer)
    cv2.putText(img, str(int(fps)), (75, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)
    cv2.imshow("Tracking", img)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff == ord('q'):
        break
```

Comment: Try this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67159209/attributeerror-module-cv2-cv2-has-no-attribute-trackermosse-create

Answer (score 6):

Actually the latest version of the opencv now has the "TrackerMOSSE_create" under the legacy class
So, instead of this

```
tracker = cv2.TrackerMOSSE_create()
```

use:

```
tracker = cv2.legacy.TrackerMOSSE_create()
```

Comment: thank you for responding me. However, i forgot to add this case because i tried it according to my video I refered. Nothing changes : 'AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'legacy' '

Answer (score 3):

TrackerMOSSE is indeed under the legacy class as stated by [@Spyke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5966313/spyke). However, Instead of:

```
tracker = cv2.legacy.TrackerMOSSE_create()
```

I was able to run MOSSE Tracker in OpenCV 4.5.1 with another kind of syntax:

```
tracker = cv2.legacy_TrackerMOSSE.create()
```

Comment: both work, checked with 4.5.2